# Washing hands after touching a gentile corpse

Tags: halacha, gentiles, death, netilat-yadayim-washing, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

Does one need to wash hands after touching a gentile corpse [just as after a Jewish one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/5114/3073)?

Comment: Can you provide any indication why you think one might have to do so? Or why you ask about only a gentile corpse?

Comment: @DoubleAA The quoted texts there do not specify a Jewish corpse.

Comment: I attended a shiur that talked about this last year (it talked about Jewish, gentile, and animal corpses) and I remember there's a machlokhet, but alas I don't remember any details (and it was on Shabbat, so no notes).

Comment: @MonicaCellio I have been wondering for years why Chaza"l didn't prohibit torah study on shabbos to prevent inadvertent writing... :-)

Comment: Let's be glad they didn't!  (I'm going to hazard a guess that there was less note-taking during their time and more focus on memory.)  Besides, *forbidding* torah study in any but the very limited cases it's forbidden now would seem to, well, run counter to the torah. :-)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Someone who must spend 1/7 of his day in the bathroom...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rambam Hilchos Tumas Mais 1:15](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/a101.htm) says that one becomes Tamei when handling a non Jewish corpse. The only difference is that a non Jewish corpse does not make one Tamei in the same building.

[Nitei Gavriel](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_46539_354.pdf) in the name of the Elya Raba says this is done to remove Tumah.